# How to redefine an attribute in inherited classes in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a generic Database structure which can store several user-defined records. For example, the main table is RECORD and the columns are STRING01, STRING02, [...], NUM01, NUM02 etc.

I know this is a bit weird, but it has advantages as well as disadvantages. However, this structure exists and can't be changed. Now I want to create some JPA classes.

First, I created an abstract class RECORD as follows (the Annotations are placed on the gettersthe example is just simplified):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Record {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name="STRING01")
    private String string01;

    @Column(name="STRING02")
    private String string02;

    @Column(name="NUM01")
    private BigDecimal num01;
}
```

Then, I created specific classes inherited from RECORD:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Person")
public class Person extends Record {
    @Transient
    public String getFirstName() {
        return getString01();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String name) {
        setString01(name);
    }

    @Transient
    public BigDecimal getWeight() {
        return getNum01();
    }

    public void setWeight(BigDecimal weight) {
        setNum01(weight);
    }
}
```

This works fine, as I can query RECORD for a PERSON's primary key (via `EntityManager.find()`) and get a Result as instance of PERSON. I can query for FirstName and Weight without having to know the generic column names.

However, if I write my own JPA Query like `SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.firstName = 'Michael'`, it fails. `firstName` is transient, and here I have to use the generic name `string01`.

Is there some way of overriding the base class' attribute name in JPA? Maybe there's a vendor-specific solution (I'm using EclipseLink)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and map multiple attributes to the same column.
The additional attribute would then be annotated with `@Column( name = "column name", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false )`.

Alternatively, you might be able to replace/enhance the JPQL resolver in order to internally map `p.firstName` to `p.string01`, but that would be EclipseLink specific, and I don't really know if that's even possible. Take this as just a hint what to look for.

Comment: Using `insertable=false, updatable=false` works for me. It's Murphy's Law, i know these parameters and their purpose, I just didn't think of using them in this context. Thanks.